# SQL Server UNION or JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I am having a bit of problem with JOIN or UNION? Would you help me solve this?

Here is my story.

I have two tables: tbl_inventory and tbl_delivery.

Here is the scenario. Each week I have to match a delivery and an inventory record. For example: on week 1 I have to show, the delivery and inventory for a specific product.

```
   Inventory Date    | Week #      |Product    |inventory qty | delivery qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2018/02/12        |  7          |cheesecake | 30           | 25          |
```

It is fine I can do that now. The problem arise when I have no delivery or no inventory for that week? Here is my desired output:

```
   Inventory Date    | Week #      |Product    |inventory qty | delivery qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2018/02/12        |  7          |cheesecake | NULL         | 25          |
```

OR

```
   Inventory Date    | Week #      |Product    |inventory qty | delivery qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2018/02/12        |  7          |cheesecake | 30           |     NULL    |
```

Would you help me achieve that? Here is my code

```html
select a.CustCode,
  b.Material,
  b.Qty as deliveryQty,
  d.Qty as inventoryQty
from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H as a

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_D as b
  on a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H as c
  on datepart(wk, a.DtRcv) = datepart(wk, c.DtRcv)

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D as d
  on c.TransCtr = d.TransCtr

  left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as e
  on b.Material = e.ExtMatGrp


UNION ALL

select a.CustCode,
  b.Material,
  d.Qty as deliveryQty,
  b.Qty as inventoryQty

from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H as a

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D as b
  on a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H as c
  on datepart(wk, a.DtRcv) = datepart(wk, c.DtRcv)

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_D as d
  on c.TransCtr = d.TransCtr

  left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as e
  on b.Material = e.ExtMatGrp
```

I have switched from using joins and union. But still I get the same result.

Here is my inventory table result:

[image: Inventory]

Here is my delivery table result:

[image]

Here is the result of my query:

[image]

As we can see, there is only one inventory but it still shows 30 on every delivery. I understand that I have used join that is why. Hope you can help me with understand UNIONs and JOIN here. Hope I explained myself clearly. Thankyou. All you suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is my new query it s outputting what I want. my problem now is how can I add there where statement? for a specific date range:

```html
select a.CustCode,
  b.Material,
  b.Qty as deliveryQty,
  NULL as inventoryQty
from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H as a

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_D as b
  on a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

  left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as e
  on b.Material = e.ExtMatGrp


UNION 

select v.CustCode,
  b.Material,
  NULL as deliveryQty,
  b.Qty as inventoryQty

from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H as v

  left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D as b
  on v.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

  left join BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as e
  on b.Material = e.ExtMatGrp
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you attach DDL for your table with insert script and the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is `UNION` which prevents you from seeing your joins result in duplication. You should use `UNION ALL`, and correct your joins to include `Material`.

E.g. something like:

```
left join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D as d
        on c.TransCtr = d.TransCtr
        and c.Material = b.Material
```

How your tables are connected is not immediately clear, but the point is you are looking for a `TransCtr` in your inventory. `TransCtr = 89` has an inventory of 30, it's just the wrong material.

Comment: Hi! Would you look at my code? I have already joined the materials table and used UNION ALL. Still the same result. It is confusing for me. I know that the JOINs are the suspect for this.